# Dynamically setting cross domain Iframe height based on content by window.postMessage

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, iframe

In my project I use Iframe to show results of editing elements inside of iFrame content by parent element. Initially I generate height of content by this:

```
iframeRef.current.contentWindow.postMessage(getIframeHeight, '*');
```

and in Iframe:

```
 window.onmessage = e => {
      if (e.data === 'getIframeHeight') {
        const iframeHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
        window.parent.postMessage(iframeHeight, '*');
      } 
    };
```

then in parent element I have listener which runs this function

```
 const setIframeHeight = val => {
    if (typeof val.data === 'number') {
      setHeight(val.data);
    }
  };
```

And so my Iframe with attribute height is set to received message.

Now the problem is that in parent element I have function that changes width of iframe to reflect diffrent devices (mobile, tablet, desktop), and when I change to mobile(height of content becomes naturally longer) I send getIframeHeight again and get again correct height. But, when I switch from mobile to desktop content gets shorter, but I receive the same height like with mobile version, and iframe is unnaturally extended with just empty space. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: So use resize event handler and send more updates on the size?